# Factory/class that extends native object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to extend the built-in Map object. This is the part that works:

```js
var Attributes = class extends Map {

    get text () {
        let out = [];
        for ( let [ k, v ] of this.entries() ) {
            out.push( k + '="' + v + '"' );
        }
        return out.join( ' ' );
    }

    // simplified for brevity!
    set text ( raw ) {
        this.clear();
        var m, r = /(\w+)="([^"]+)"/g;
        while ( ( m = r.exec( raw ) ) ) {
            this.set( m[1], m[2] );
        }
    }
};

var a = new Attributes();
a.text = 'id="first"';
console.log( a.get( 'id' ) ); // first
a.set( 'id', 'second' );
console.log( a.text ); // id="second"
```

But I want to integrate this class seamlessly into my library and rather expose a factory method that serves a double purpose as a constructor. Users don't need to know that this particular method is unusual. It would just complicate things. My own code however needs to be able to use instanceof for input validation purposes. This is what I'm going for:

```js
var obj = {};
obj.attr = function ( text ) {
    if ( new.target ) {
        this.text = text;
    } else {
        return new obj.attr( text );
    }
};

console.log( obj.attr() instanceof obj.attr ); // true
```

The above, too, works. However, no matter how I try to combine the two approaches, both Chrome and Firefox throw various Errors. The code below e.g. throws a TypeError "this.entries(...)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function":

```js
var obj = {};
obj.attr = function ( text ) {
    if ( new.target ) {
        this.text = text;
    } else {
        return new obj.attr( text );
    }
};

obj.attr.prototype = Object.assign( new Map(), {
    get text () {
        let out = [];
        for ( let [ k, v ] of this.entries() ) {
            out.push( k + '="' + v + '"' );
        }
        return out.join( ' ' );
    },
    // simplified for brevity!
    set text ( raw ) {
        this.clear();
        var m, r = /(\w+)="([^"]+)"/g;
        while ( ( m = r.exec( raw ) ) ) {
            this.set( m[1], m[2] );
        }
    }
} );
```

What am I missing and/or misunderstanding here?

Update: It *would* be possible using `Object.setPrototypeOf()` but the performance penalty would probably be substantial. It's *also* possible using `Reflect.construct()`. It's not obvious to me though how exactly this differs from `Object.setPrototypeOf()`. Reflect seems to be generally slow since apparently no current browser has optimizations for it.

```js
var Attributes = class extends Map {
    
    constructor ( text ) {
        super();
        this.text = text;
    }
    
    get text () {
        let out = [];
        for ( let [ k, v ] of this.entries() ) {
            out.push( k + '="' + v + '"' );
        }
        return out.join( ' ' );
    }
    
    // simplified for brevity!
    set text ( raw ) {
        this.clear();
        if ( !raw ) return;
        var m, r = /(\w+)="([^"]+)"/g;
        while ( ( m = r.exec( raw ) ) ) {
            this.set( m[1], m[2] );
        }
    }
};

var obj = {};

obj.attr = function ( text ) {
    if ( new.target ) {
        return Reflect.construct( Attributes, [ text ], obj.attr );
    } else {
        return new obj.attr( text );
    }
};

obj.attr.prototype = Object.create( Attributes.prototype );

console.log( obj.attr() instanceof obj.attr );
console.log( obj.attr() instanceof Attributes );
console.log( obj.attr() instanceof Map );

var a = obj.attr();
a.text = 'id="first"';
console.log( a.get( 'id' ) );
a.set( 'id', 'second' );
console.log( a.text );
```

Comment: Sorry, so you want to be able to use both `new Attributes(...)` and `Attributes(...)`?

Comment: Yes. Well, kind of. In the docs I'll tell users to use `obj.attr()`. I plan to omit that `new obj.attr()` would work as well.

Comment: you wrote that this.entries throws an error but you don't include the code of this.entries method.

Comment: I was hoping that `obj.attr.prototype = Object.assign( new Map(), { /*...*/ } );` would do the trick. `entries` is a method of the Map object after all. However, this clearly doesn't work but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not working because Object.assign doesnt copy getters/setters, but calls them. So the getter (get text) is called with *this* being *window* , which will obviosly fail:

[MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object. It uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters. This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters. For copying property definitions, including their enumerability, into prototypes Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor() and Object.defineProperty() should be used instead.

To copy the object into the Map without loosing the setters, may do:

```
obj.attr.prototype = new Map();
var settings = {
  get text(){},
  set text(v){}
};

for(key in settings){
  Object.defineProperty(
    obj.attr.prototype,
    key,
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(settings,key)
  );
}
```

However, this will still fail. Maps are different from objects. Calling *this.clear()* will crash as it expects *this* to be a map and not a regular object. So there are two options left:

1) use the class syntax and a factory:

```
 {
  let internal = class extends Map {
   constructor(text){
     super();
     this.text = text;
   };
   set text(v){};
   get text(){};
  };

  var obj = {
   attr(text){
     return new internal(text);
    }
  };
}
```

2) keep the map internally:

```
 obj.attr = function(text){
   if(this === window) return new obj.attr(text);
   this.map = new Map();
   this.text = text;
};
obj.attr.prototype = {
  set text(v){
   this.map.set("text",v);
  },
  get text(){
   return this.map.get("text");
  }
};
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I still can't seem to get it to work though. Check my edit, please!

Comment: Sure. Maps aren't POJOs but `obj.attr.prototype = new Map();` should turn `obj.attr` objects into regular Map objects, no? When I add `console.log( this )` to the setter and the getter, I see exactly the extended Map object I expect to see.

Comment: @peter coester *The Map constructor is designed to be subclassable. It may be used as the value in an extends clause of a class definition. Subclass constructors that intend to inherit the specified Map behaviour must include a super call to the Map constructor to create and initialize the subclass instance with the internal state necessary to support the Map.prototype built-in methods.* and no, youre not doing an initialization call in your code. Your object us just a regular object, which has a Map instance as prototype

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. How is `new Map()` not an initialization?

Comment: @peter coester its the prototype. Object.getPrototypeOf( obj.attr() ) will return a real Map.

Comment: Okay. I think I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind checking out my update? It seems to work with `Reflect.construct()`.

Comment: @peter coester i think the upper two solutions are much much easier than such meta programming...